Windows 11 erases GRUB data making booting into Linux painful
It's not exactly a "dual boot" question, because I'm not installing Kali Linux on an internal drive. The situation is that I install Kali on an external/removable hard drive from a USB stick using Ventoy. I've set the BIOS boot priorities to cycle through the USB attachments first, before booting from the internal drive that houses the copy of Windows 11. So it all works fine as long as I don't boot into Win11 while the thing is plugged in. Removing the drive before booting into Win11, prevents Win11 from deleting the GRUB data that keeps it in a stable boot configuration, with GRUB installed on the removable drive. But as soon as Win11 boots, it reaches into my USB drive and messes with it, which it shouldn't do but that's besides the point... How do I fix it, should I forget to unplug it, so I don't have to keep reinstalling the whole thing using Ventoy?
For reference, this post most closely reflects the situation currently: Resolving Kali Linux booting issue with GNU Grub in dual-boot with Windows
Sad that it has so many down-votes. They were obviously doing something right if they got as far as the initramfs promp. Did a bit of digging into GRUB commands and how to get it all set back up, copied command-line arguments from a working system, and came up with this:
grub> linux (hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.11-amd64 BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.11-amd64 root=UUID=[uuid-of-drive] ro quiet splash
grub> inirtrd (hd0,gpt2)/boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-amd64

Which brings me to this screen:

Which lead me to that post about kali/win dual boot, and inspired me to create this one: Where would someone go from here? Is there a boot parameter or something I'm missing? How does one go about getting it to boot normally again from GRUB?

Did you try what the answer to the post you linked suggests? More to the point, why are you trying to fix the symptom instead of the cause? Why not try to get Windows to stop messing with your drive? And are you sure it even does? Where is grub installed? How did you install it? With what command? Finally, are you sure you want Kali? Using Kali just makes everything much more complicated without providing any benefit unless you are a professional pen-tester. It is absolutely the worst choice for someone learning Linux or for someone who wants to use Linux.

Windows was always an "elephant in the room", meaning it never was designed to work with any other OS. As such, it needs to be installed first in any kind of dual-boot configuration. I have no experience with Windows 11, but if it is the cause of the issue here, it probably controls booting more aggressively, unlike previous versions.

"Did you try what the answer to the post you linked suggests?"
Yeah that's how I got to the initramfs screen.
"Why not try to get Windows to stop messing with your drive?"
I listed everything, all the information is there. Grub is installed on the USB drive that Kali is installed on, so it can boot without having to go through the boot-loader on the internal drive. I'm not "just learning linux", new to GRUB though: These are two separate yet related issues.

"... but if it is the cause of the issue here, ..." Vilinkameni yeah I tested it a few times, same each time: Booting into Win11 with the USB drive plugged in screws up GRUB so bad I can't boot as normal. If someone else wants to use the computer and boots into Win11 while I'm not looking and they don't know to unplug it, I have to reinstall.

I don't use Kali, but Win11 likes to format my Linux USB stick for no reason. I worked around it by giving all partitions the Microsoft data type and set attributes hidden, do not automount. That way, Win11 leaves the stick well alone. However, from your description, your issue seems to be different (unless it did format and that's why your UUID can't be found).

For testing purposes you could also try your luck with a readonly USB stick (USB SD card reader with readonly switch on the card).


Where would someone go from here? Is there a boot parameter or something I'm missing?

There's far too little detail in your question to say what you missed. But since you appear to be stuck at this stage, I'll try to offer some sign-posts to help you understand where you are and what to look for.  This type of problem is one of the reasons we regularly say Kali is pentesters and usually requires Linux experts.
Where are you stuck?
BIOS --> EFI stub --> Grub --> Initramfs --> Running System (systemd)
Each of these steps is configurable on laptops and desktops. Some embedded hardware doesn't have a configurable BIOS in quite the same way.

BIOS - software and configuration on the motherboard. Consult your motherboard's user manual for reconfiguring it
EFI "stub" ("grub stub") is usually a binary and single configuration file grub.cfg stored in EFI. The config file is just enough to tell grub where to find its main configuration file.
Grub - The same program as the "stub" continues to load the main configuration file and any necessary modules. The main configuration file is usually NOT on EFI and is stored in /boot/grub in the running system's filesystem. So in practice, that's the main Kali partition if you don't have a dedicated /boot partition.
Initramfs is a temporary file system loaded by the bootloader when it also loads Linux. It contains kernel modules and configuration scripts that mount just enough of the main filesystem(s) to launch the system manager (systemd).
Running system - The system manager is responsible for running everything else, and if it ever died, the whole system would "panic". The system manager is entirely loaded from the main root filesystem.

What to check?
Well, there's a lot to check.
Just because you managed to get into initramfs, doesn't mean it was launched with all the right parameters, and it doesn't mean the system is laid out as it expects.

With a removable drive, it's likely you have two EFI partitions: one on the drive with MS Windows and the other on the removable drive with Kali.
Check that you have just one grub stub in only one EFI partition. I've never seen MS Windows "mess with" other installs, but I've seen it completely wipe and rewrite EFI. If you have two grub stubs, one correctly configured and the other broken, then Windows might wipe EFI and leave you with only the broken one.

Grub stub must be configured to find the right drive.
Check that the grub.cfg in EFI correctly points to the drive with /boot/grub on and pay attention to the prefix. It depends on whether you have a separate boot partition or not. With no separate partition, it should look like this:
search.fs_uuid 9df3be1d-f619-4991-af0c-2c556f66595f root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


From Grub, see if you can manually run that configuration. For example, type:
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

This may give you a more tangible error to work with.

You can read the contents of (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub to see what the correct parameters for linux and initramfs are.

Inside initramfs, check what happens when you try to mount your partition manually with mount. Mount using the same UUID=[uuid-of-drive] you mentioned in your question. Check that the file system you mounted is definitely the one you intended.  Check it has /usr/sbin/init.



The point about the GRUB prefix handling for the configuration file is really important here, and is something people often do not think about. That needs to be right for removable media to reliably work correctly, because removable media enumeration ordering relative to everything else in the system varies by system (some firmware enumerates it before internal media, some after, some mixes things, and some does not actually alter the apparent enumeration order based on what’s being booted like it’s supposed to).

"Check that you have just one grub stub in only one EFI partition. I've never seen MS Windows 'mess with' other installs, but I've seen it completely wipe and rewrite EFI."
Seems that the owner had installed the WSL and there is a "phantom" Ubuntu install on the internal HD showing up in a faulty(?) GRUB install. Something about that was doing what you said it is doing. So it was Windows, but it wasn't Windows at the same time lol.
I went and got another drive of the same type and manufacturer to test, and the problem has been fixed after running update-grub from a rescue USB on the drive.

@Chadwicke Sounds like you have a solution. Can you post that as an answer?


Removing the drive before booting into Win11, prevents Win11 from deleting the GRUB data that keeps it in a stable boot configuration, with GRUB installed on the removable drive.

I'm pretty sure that is not what is happening. What is happening is that your UEFI system sees your two different UEFI-capable boot loaders, you select windows, and at next boot, the internal order is different, and because your grub and initrd aren't set up to find devices regardless of their numbering, things stop to work.
Solution is to simply not do it that way: The easy part here is making sure your initrd's fstab doesn't contain things like /dev/sda1, but uses UUIDs, which are untouched by the internal device ordering.
I don't think the post you're referring to has too much technical resemblance to your situation (they're using GRUB on an MSDOS partitioned MBR boot system, you're using GRUB2 on an GPT-partitioned EFI system, yet with a strange man in the middle, this ventoy thing).
I think if you just didn't use ventoy, chances are that a direct installation to the external medium would just work.
In any case, this really doesn't sound like Windows' fault at all.

At the behest of wizwiz4's urging, I have posted an answer to my own question. I did not test a "read-only" USB drive as frostschutz suggested, simply because if something can write to the drive all that means is I have a faulty read-only mechanism.
A WORD ON "requires Linux experts"
I disagree that Kali Linux requires expert knowledge to handle. It's basically a Debian distribution, with a ton of pentesting tools preinstalled. Other than that you could use it as your daily just fine, even if you uninstalled all the pentesting tools. Every apt package I've tested on Kali works, and works well. They seem real intent on keeping things of the highest quality possible, even for the non-pentesting things! So take the plunge, break your system, install something dangerous and don't look back! It's all in your head, really. Don't let it scare you. Reading the error messages and following the trail to fixing all the things is a perilous, but rewarding journey.
Familiarity breeds success, and being able to just "muscle memory" your way through the terminal is great. Oh and random tip for using apt, always
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
before you
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Because this way it doesn't break everything, and after years of testing that, doing it in that order matters.
MORE TESTING: REPRODUCING THE ERROR
Two people have Windows 11 installed on their CPUs, tested it with both getting the same results: After leaving the USB drive plugged in to a machine running Windows 11, at some point I am no longer able to normally boot from the USB drive. In my original question I mentioned that it's different than from an internal drive, and what I mean by that is twofold: The protocol for SATA and USB is different (software), and, they are two different hardware layers. This will be real important later. At the UEFI (BIOS) level, you can set this so it boots from one or the other. On the machines tested today, it somehow removes the USB drive from visibility to the UEFI system upon reboot. Not sure how, but booting into GRUB2 is still possible.
So today I spent a majority of the day proving to myself that I'm not crazy, and here were my results... After installing OpenBSD (using Ventoy, huge shout-out to an amazing piece of software, real time-saver) on one of the two USB drives previously mentioned in this experiment, I booted it from this machine and installed xfce4 one component at a time (not the meta package), rebooting each time back into Kali Linux to listen to a song. Neither system broke, and booting from Kali to OpenBSD wasn't a problem. At all. Ever. I could only ever get to maybe 4 or 5 reboots on a Windows 11 machine before something just happened, and couldn't boot into the USB drive normally again. After finally getting xfce4 all set up and installing a web browser, I listened to a few songs while on OpenBSD, because I could. Then I rebooted into Kali to post this.
AVOIDING THE INITRAMFS TERMINAL
After much lament I bit the bullet to read the quest text, and booting the system from the GRUB2 command-line isn't so bad after all. Getting it all set up correctly before booting is essential to getting all the way to the login screen. I had only been missing one parameter this entire time. Poking around in the /boot/ folder of the USB drive, I noticed there was a file named "config-6.8.11-amd64" matching the pattern of other named boot files in that folder. Coincidentally, there is a GRUB2 command aptly named "configfile", which is nice.
GETTING TO NORMAL MODE
So first off when in GRUB2, it helps if you're in "normal mode". Usually if you're already in normal mode, the console prompt looks like this:
grub> 
The only other mode I know is rescue mode, and the terminal looks like this if it is:
grub rescue>
If you're here, first set the "pager" option to 1, so text on the screen can be paged like the command "less" in most Linux distros.
grub rescue> set pager=1
As Austin Hemmelgarn mentions, it's important to see if the "prefix" variable is properly set. If you're in grub rescue it is probably not set right, and could even mean that the drive itself might have errors. Anyway, Before setting it to something, check to see if it is already set by typing the following.
grub rescue> echo $prefix
If the terminal spits out a blank line or nothing, it means it is not set. So the next step is to locate the USB drive where GRUB2 is installed.
grub rescue> ls -l
This should give you a list of all the attached drives. Usually if your UEFI-"BIOS" is working correctly, and you set it to list USB drives first, then (hd0,gpt2) should be the drive and partition grub was installed to. (Something, something, this knowledge came in handy later). This should be the reason you're in a GRUB2 terminal in the first place, that at least the EFI-stub=>to=>GRUB2 Philip Couling mentioned, worked correctly. Mind you, this is a drive that was installed with Kali Linux using the "whole drive and home folder all in one" newbie option. This option creates 3 partitions on the drive: A ~512 MB UEFI partition, a root partition, and a swap partition. Unless something really bad happened, the UEFI partition should be (hd0,gpt1), root and boot is (hd0,gpt2), and swap is (hd0,gpt3). In my case it was, so I typed...
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,gpt2)
And...
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
Then...
grub rescue> insmod normal
Finally...
grub rescue> normal
This should momentarily blank the screen or even reboot, but upon arrival to the terminal once more, it should finally look like this...
grub> 
ONCE IN 'NORMAL' GRUB2 MODE
Moving to normal mode might have reset the pager option, so I usually reset this.
grub> set pager=1
Recheck environment variables...
grub> echo $root
and
grub> echo $prefix
It should still be set to what it was set to last time. If not, reset as shown in the previous section. I Then typed...
grub> linux (hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.11-amd64 root=UUID=[UUID-of-drive] ro quiet splash
No output means it worked, and GRUB2 has now set the path to the kernel and its startup command-line options. It will give an error if it can't access the drive, or you typed it wrong. Also, getting the UUID of the drive is easy, and can be done from the GRUB2 terminal by typing...
grub> ls -l
Otherwise you should have the UUID of the drive written down before doing this, but in most cases it shouldn't be necessary. If you need to though, a working machine can easily fetch these numbers by plugging the drive in and clicking on the properties tab after right-clicking on the drive, for most desktop environments. Next, set the initial ram disk by typing...
grub> initrd (hd0,gpt2)/boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-amd64
No output, again, means it worked correctly. Now type...
grub> configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/config-6.8.11-amd64
No output? Good. This was the one thing I was missing last time. Without the config file, it should drop you into the initramfs prompt upon booting every time. With the config file, the splash screen should briefly show up, and then you should get the login prompt from there. So finally, type
grub> boot
And that's it. [edit] Well, sort of. From inside the system once it's back up and running, open a terminal and run...
update-grub
That should make things permanent, until they're changed again for some unknown reason.
INITRAMFS TERMINAL?
If the system isn't booting properly but it still gets to the initramfs prompt, it is possible to run a drive check and then reboot into a working system, but that is a tutorial for another day perhaps. The tldr is that you might first have to type "exit" to get out of the BusyBox terminal and into the real initramfs terminal, like so:
initramfs) exit
It should drop you into another terminal that looks exactly like the previous one. Then perform the drive check...
initramfs) fsck -fy [path/to/drive]
And reboot. It should work, but if not, then you should post your own question.

The "requies experts" thing is complicated. Historically Kali's config has rarely been ready to go out of the box, where Debian and Ubuntu are. A lot of users get dropped off the map into some unknown shell or obscure error. A very experienced linux user will, in most cases understand the error and just go fix the config in the right component. But without that experience many users are left without knowing what went wrong. You seem to be more comfortable finding your way out of the problem that many Kali users we get here.

True it used to be a bit more complicated, the installer "just works" in most cases now. But overall seems more like those entry-level positions that require experience... My intent being encouragement for newer users, nothing more! Get that experience!

I haven't used Windows 11 but I have seen Windows 10 seem to delete GRUB before. It doesn't delete it, it changes the boot order. You need to fix it from Windows and Microsoft explain how to here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/windows-11-and-secure-boot-a8ff1202-c0d9-42f5-940f-843abef64fad

I’ve seen it delete the boot stub entirely by formatting the EFI partition and reinstalling windows boot loader.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/windows-deleted-grub/140973

That link includes others who claim to have personally witnessed what myself and 2 others here claim to have personally witnessed. It would be fine to claim that in your case it did not delete it. But the disagreement seems to point to it happening under specific circumstances, even if others cannot reproduce it.
